# onActivityResult not returning value

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am developing an app that takes a picture, resizes and puts it into an imageview. My camera intent starts and takes a picture but the picture is not being returned to the imageview. The picture was being returned before I added a new line in my manifest to save my activity state so that when I navigate to another activity and back, the state on my activity will be returned.

I have put my code for my intent, `onActivityResult` and manifest.

```
case R.id.image1_1:   
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, 11);   
    break; 


@Override                                                                                                                            
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Teracore", "onActivityResult");
    if (requestCode == 11 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        view1_1.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                (int) (bmp.getWidth() * 0.4),
                (int) (bmp.getHeight() * 0.35), true));
    }
}

<activity
    android:name=".Management"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.mba_north.MANAGEMENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: can you post your log ?

Comment: have you added setResult(RESULT_OK,intent); before finishing your second activity?

Comment: the logcat is not indicating anything usual @manoj pal

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Is `Log.d` print `onActivityResult` in logcat or not?

Comment: No,i realised it was only being called with i navigate to another activity and not when i want to take a picture @Gunaseelan